# AWS SES processing delay

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

We are sending emails with SES.

There seems to be delays in emails arriving for some users. For other users, emails arrive almost instantly. I've switched on notifications and can see the `processingTimeMillis` is extremely high for some emails:

```
{
    "notificationType": "Delivery",
    "mail": {
        "timestamp": "2016-04-14T14:02:50.000Z",
        "source": "noreply@gmail.com",
        "sourceArn": "...",
        "sendingAccountId": "884660938610",
        "messageId": "...",
        "destination": ["foo@bar.com"]
    },
    "delivery": {
        "timestamp": "2016-04-14T14:19:29.072Z",
        "processingTimeMillis": 999072,
        "recipients": ["foo@bar.com"],
        "smtpResponse": "250 sdfgdsg@sdgdsgds.com Received OK",
        "reportingMTA": "abcdef.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com"
    }
}
```

I've read around online but haven't been able to see what may cause these types of delays.

Email addresses and domains are all verified.

I've removed account specific information from the above. The processing time value was not changed.

Comment: do you see a pattern for domains where the delivery takes a long time? it may be that the mail servers/relays are slower

Comment: No pattern visible as yet, I'm keeping an eye on it but it seems to be random so far...

Comment: Is this happening for a specific set of accounts within your organization, or is it randomly happening to random users?

Comment: There are a vast multitude of reasons why email may be delayed, including overloads and outages on the receiving end, and inbound policies that prevent delivery of mail faster than a specified number of message per unit of time, which SES has no choice but to abide by, to prevent running afoul of recipient systems' rules, otherwise resulting in outright rejection of mail for being "too aggressive."  You're looking at a delay of less than 17 minutes, here, which, to me, is not worth even noticing unless a pattern emerges, and even then it may be out if SES's control.

Comment: OK so I've found that emails to a particular server are being consistently delayed whereas emails to Gmail seem to be going through instantly. Am I right that this is caused by the end server rather than SES? And is there anything I can do to reduce this or is it outside my control?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to those who commented, led me to find the answer.

There were several email servers which were delaying the emails from being delivered to the inboxes.

SES was sending these correctly and quickly however once they arrived at the destination server, this was taking time to process and release.